Are Jackie Estacado and Ian Nottingham brothers?
I'll try to explain why I think that they are.
In Witchblade #10 (November 1996), the narrative establishes that Jackie Estacado is an orphan who was all but adopted into the Franchetti Family. However, one big indicator is Sara Pezzini's reaction when she sees his face for the first time.

She is shocked because he looks just like Ian Nottingham. For the record, Ian Nottingham looks like this.

Yes, both men have similar builds, similar facial features and long black hair. Both of them are killers, even though Jackie works for an Italian crime family whereas Ian works for a Japanese crime family.
There is one other detail that needs mentioning. In Witchblade: Destiny's Child #1 (June 1, 2000), Ian says that he was torn from his brother, his only living relative, at the age of eight, and that he doesn't remember much of him and hasn't a clue of his life or whereabouts now.
I understand that Witchblade: Destiny's Child is not canon, but I can't help but wonder if his brother is none other than Jackie Estacado.

That's unlikely. For starters, it would be strange they wouldn't recognise each other, even if they were parted as 8-year-olds. There's also the issue of what happens when Darkness wielder has children... which limits options a bit ;)
